# Cropping a map made with geom_polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a map using `geom_polygon`:

```
## libraries
library(tidyverse)

## render map
map_data("state") %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "gray") +
  coord_map(projection = "albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

The map renders correctly, however, as you will see, there is a ton of white space on either side of the map:

[image]

Is there anyway to automatically crop the map so as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add limits to your `coord_map` call.

```
map_data("state") %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "gray") +
  coord_map(projection = "albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45,
            xlim = c(-117,-75), ylim = c(26,49)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

Then make sure your graphics device has dimensions that match your plot:

```
ggsave("~/temp.png",width = 1.55 * 5, height = 5)
```

[image]